# translateX element when another element is on hover

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make a swiper slider using CSS and this what I got so far
HTML

```
 <section id="lakeSlider" class="carousel vcenter-item py-5">
        <div>
            <div class="carousel__container">
                <div class="carousel-item carousel-index1">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="carousel-item__img img-fluid"
                            src="./assets/images/cards/oserenfloatingcardimageindex2.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="card-body pb-0">
                            <h5 class="text-center card-title">Mila Hubert</h5>
                            <p class="card-text text-center">Sales Manager</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item carousel-index2">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="carousel-item__img img-fluid"
                            src="./assets/images/cards/oserenfloatingcardimageindex2.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="card-body pb-0">
                            <h5 class="text-center card-title">Boris Komnenov</h5>
                            <p class="card-text text-center">Marketing Manager</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item carousel-index3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="carousel-item__img img-fluid"
                            src="./assets/images/cards/oserenfloatingcardimage.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="card-body pb-0">
                            <h5 class="text-center card-title">Joshua Rubens</h5>
                            <p class="card-text text-center">CEO</p>
                            <div class="cardbodydownarrow text-center m-0 p-0"><img
                                    src="./assets/images/icon/oserendownarrowpix.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item carousel-index4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="carousel-item__img img-fluid"
                            src="./assets/images/cards/oserenfloatingcardimageindex2.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="card-body pb-0">
                            <h5 class="text-center card-title">Anna Jimenez</h5>
                            <p class="card-text text-center">Product Designer</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item carousel-index5">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="carousel-item__img img-fluid"
                            src="./assets/images/cards/oserenfloatingcardimageindex2.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="card-body pb-0">
                            <h5 class="text-center card-title">Ben Hubert</h5>
                            <p class="card-text text-center">Programmer</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
/* lakeSlider */

#lakeSlider .carousel {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#lakeSlider .carousel__container {
    margin: 70px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#lakeSlider .categories__title {
    color: rgb(77, 55, 102);
    font-size: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

#lakeSlider .carousel-item {
    width: 280px;
    margin: 50px 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: 1000ms all;
    transition: 1000ms all;
}

#lakeSlider .carousel-index1, #lakeSlider .carousel-index2 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
    transform-origin: center left;
}

#lakeSlider .carousel-index4, #lakeSlider .carousel-index5 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center right;
    transform-origin: center right;
}

#lakeSlider .carousel-index3 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    transform-origin: center center;
}

@media (min-width:960px) {
    #lakeSlider .carousel-item:hover~.carousel-item {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
    }

    #lakeSlider .carousel__container:hover .carousel-item {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}

@media (min-width:960px) {
    #lakeSlider .carousel__container:hover .carousel-item:hover {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
        transform: scale(1.3);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@media (max-width:960px) {
    #lakeSlider .carousel__container:hover .carousel-item:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

#lakeSlider .card-body {
    background-color: #2699FB;
    color: white;
}

#lakeSlider .card-body h5 {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

#lakeSlider .card-body p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rrgW.png)
this what is happening now:
When I hover on any card from them all elements on the right of the one I hovered is moving to the right 100px.

this what I need to happen :

- when hovering on any of the first two elements(1st,2nd) from the left, all right elements move to the right 100px.
  *when hovering on the middle one (3rd), the first two elements move to the left 100px and the last two elements move to the right 100px.
  *when hovering on the any of the last two elements (4th,5th), all left elements move to the left 100px.
  Thank you for your patience and your help.

I tried to change this line

```
@media (min-width:960px) {
    #lakeSlider .carousel-item:hover~.carousel-item {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
    }
```

to be

```
    #lakeSlider .carousel-index4:hover~.carousel-index1 {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
    }
```

and custom all carousel-index for each one but it didn't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major browsers (except Firefox which requires the user to set a flag) now implement the CSS :has pseudo class.

This snippet uses this on the container element to sense when one of the items has been hovered. If so, it translates all items -100px (note, the transform-origin is left at its default center center position for all the items).

It then overrides this for the items to the right of the hovered item by translating  them 100px. And it translates the hovered item by 0.

```html
<!document html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* lakeSlider */

#lakeSlider .carousel {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#lakeSlider .carousel__container {
    margin: 70px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#lakeSlider .categories__title {
    color: rgb(77, 55, 102);
    font-size: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

#lakeSlider .carousel-item {
    width: 280px;
    margin: 50px 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: 1000ms all;
    transition: 1000ms all;
}

@media (min-width:960px) {
#lakeSlider .carousel__container:has(.carousel-item:hover) .carousel-item {
  transform: translateX(-100px);
  opacity 0.3;
}
#lakeSlider .carousel__container .carousel-item:hover ~ .carousel-item {
  transform: translateX(100px);
}
#lakeSlider .carousel__container:has(.carousel-item:hover) .carousel-item:hover {
  transform: translateX(0) scale(1.3);
  opacity: 1;
}
}

@media (max-width:960px) {
    #lakeSlider .carousel__container:hover .carousel-item:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

#lakeSlider .card-body {
    background-color: #2699FB;
    color: white;
}

#lakeSlider .card-body h5 {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

#lakeSlider .card-body p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <section id="lakeSlider" class="carousel vcenter-item py-5">
        <div>
            <div class="carousel__container">
                <div class="carousel-item carousel-index1">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="carousel-item__img img-fluid"
                            src="./assets/images/cards/oserenfloatingcardimageindex2.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="card-body pb-0">
                            <h5 class="text-center card-title">Mila Hubert</h5>
                            <p class="card-text text-center">Sales Manager</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item carousel-index2">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="carousel-item__img img-fluid"
                            src="./assets/images/cards/oserenfloatingcardimageindex2.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="card-body pb-0">
                            <h5 class="text-center card-title">Boris Komnenov</h5>
                            <p class="card-text text-center">Marketing Manager</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item carousel-index3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="carousel-item__img img-fluid"
                            src="./assets/images/cards/oserenfloatingcardimage.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="card-body pb-0">
                            <h5 class="text-center card-title">Joshua Rubens</h5>
                            <p class="card-text text-center">CEO</p>
                            <div class="cardbodydownarrow text-center m-0 p-0"><img
                                    src="./assets/images/icon/oserendownarrowpix.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item carousel-index4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="carousel-item__img img-fluid"
                            src="./assets/images/cards/oserenfloatingcardimageindex2.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="card-body pb-0">
                            <h5 class="text-center card-title">Anna Jimenez</h5>
                            <p class="card-text text-center">Product Designer</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item carousel-index5">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="carousel-item__img img-fluid"
                            src="./assets/images/cards/oserenfloatingcardimageindex2.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="card-body pb-0">
                            <h5 class="text-center card-title">Ben Hubert</h5>
                            <p class="card-text text-center">Programmer</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```